# Submitting eCommerce analytics to Google Analytics prior to completing transaction

Tags: google-analytics

We're using Google Analytics to track transactions, products, browser data, etc on our shopping cart. I am interested in pushing some data to GA prior to completing the transaction. Normally I push data to GA on the success/order confirmation page.

My Question: **If I push custom variables to Google Analytics prior to completing an order, will GA be able to associate that session with my completed transaction - allowing me to cross reference my custom variables with the transaction IDs?**

Background: We use an address validation service and sometimes the address that the validation service submits to us isn't correct. It can "over correct" and completely strip vital details from certain addresses. Happens less than 1% of the time but when that is multiplied against 1000 - 2000 orders a day it can really become a problem for our fulfillment department. Yes, we have reported this to the address validation service and they tell us they are investigating it. I plan to use jQuery to grab the form data in the billing and shipping fields and when the user fills out all necessary fields, do a push to GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you should be able to set a session-level custom variable (a unique id or any other value that isn't PII) prior to the transaction, and then create a custom report in GA that looks at that custom variable against the transaction Id. Because it's a session-level variable, it will associate anything that happens for that session.

More info on session-level variables here - [Custom Variables - Web Tracking (ga.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)

Comment: Thank you Blexy! That is exactly what I needed. I will log events for a day or two and comment if there are any unexpected results.

Comment: @deeperDATA, great! Please let me know if you have any issues.